# ffmpeg overlay image with fade in and fade out

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, mp4

So I had a PNG overlay a video, and this was working perfectly, now I want the same png that worked previously only show for a certain duration, and have it fade in and fade out.

But my new command just has no image, where in the past it had the image.

Can you please assist, maybe I am just attempting it incorrectly.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "20180523152257.mp4" -i "20180523152257.mp4.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,fade=in:st=1:d=3:alpha=1,fade=out:st=6:d=3:alpha=1 [ovr]; [0][ovr] overlay" -codec:a copy "OUT.mp4"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i "20180523152257.mp4" -loop 1 -t 9 -i "20180523152257.mp4.png" ...
```

A single image is treated by ffmpeg as a video of one frame, but for animated effects, you need enough frames to apply the effect. The `loop` option tells ffmpeg to repeat the image indefinitely and `-t 9` limits it to 9 seconds which is when the fade out ends.